# how to get unchecked checkbox value in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

this is html code

```
<p>
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model='add_product.kids' class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box1" />
   <label for="filled-in-box1">Kids</label>
</p>
```

I need to get the value as false when the check box is unchecked ..

I print the model like this

```
console.log($scope.add_product)
```

but in that model the checkbox value is not showned ?

Can anybody hepl me ... Thanks in advance ..

Comment: When you are logging $scope.add_product?

Comment: 'app.controller('add_product_ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

 $scope.addProfileDetail = function(file) {
  
  //HERE
  console.log($scope.console.log($scope.add_product))
 }
}])'

Comment: Check my answer below for working with checkboxes or post a minimal working version in plnkr, jsbin..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access checkbox in the following ways

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("MyController",['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.checkboxModel = {
       value1 : true,
       value2 : 'YES'
     };
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
<label>Value1:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value1">
</label>
<br/>
<label>Value2:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value2" ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'">
</label>
<br/>
<tt>value1 = {{checkboxModel.value1}}</tt>
<br/>
<tt>value2 = {{checkboxModel.value2}}</tt>
<br/>
  </div>
```

Comment: @Elamparithi.P  I'm glad it helped. :)